# Garden plant identification

Tags: identification

[image]
What is that giant, amazing bush in the bottom right of the photo, under the magnificent Wisteria?

Comment: What a beautiful nook!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's an ornamental spurge. I think "Euphorbia characias, subspecies. wulfenii".
According to [vancouverislandgrows](https://vancouverislandgrows.wordpress.com/2016/05/16/euphorbia-characias-subsp-wulfenii/), it's drought- and deer-resistant too.